# Calling scanf after cout

Tags: c++, scanf, cout

I have written a small piece of code combining ***cout*** and ***scanf*** where ***cout*** prints a statement and then ***scanf*** reads a value into an integer variable ***age***. But the statement is not being printed until I enter some value for age and press enter. Please find the code below. I am trying this code on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main(){    
int age;
std::cout << "Please enter your age: ";
scanf("%d", &age);
std::cout << "Hello, your age is: " << age << std::endl;
return 1;
}
```

Comment: thats how it should work right?

Comment: Use `flush`: `std::cout << "Please enter your age: " << std::flush;`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think it's better to convert your comment to an answer and provide some more details

Comment: In general it's best not to mix C and C++ I/O - since this is supposed to be a C++ program you should use `cin` for input, rather than `scanf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the statement is not being printed until I enter some value for age and press enter.

That's because `std::cout` buffers output either up to a certain length or an explicit [`flush()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) call is applied.

So to force outputting the prompt line write:

```
   std::cout << "Please enter your age: " << std::flush;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative ways could be putting std::endl; at the end of

```
std::cout << "Please enter your age:"<<std::endl;
```

std::endl will output a newline and flush the stream.